# django: get() returned more than one Freelancers -- it returned 3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

i am trying to assign a freelancer to a particular gig but it shows get() returned more than one Freelancers -- it returned 3!. I have tried getting the logged in freelancer to is trying to create the git like this `freelancer = get_object_or_404(Freelancers, user=user)`  and before i save the form i assign the value like this  `new_form.creator = freelancer` .

views.py

```
@login_required
def create_gig(request):
    user = request.user
    freelancer = get_object_or_404(Freelancers, user=user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateGig(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user = request.user
            new_form.creator = freelancer
            new_form.slug = slugify(new_form.title)
            
            new_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Gig Created Successfully, Would be Live Soon')
            return redirect('freelance:listings')
    else:
        form = CreateGig()
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'freelance/create.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Gigs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gig_user')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Freelancers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gig_creator')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Enter what you will do", default=" I will ")
```

Comment: `get_object_or_404` will return one instance if it encounters more than one instance maching the filter it will generate exception. Check your `Freelancers` it would have 3 instance of user.

Comment: Show your Freelancers model, that might help to narrow down why you're getting 3 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code, it is getting a logged-in user instance and then creating the gig by assigning the freelancer to the created form.

```
@login_required
    def create_gig(request):
        freelancer = Freelancers.objects.get(user = request.user )
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateGig(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_form = form.save(commit=False)
                new_form.creator = freelancer
                new_form.slug = slugify(new_form.title)
                
                new_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Gig Created Successfully, Would be Live Soon')
                return redirect('freelance:listings')
        else:
            form = CreateGig()
        context = {
            'form': form
            }
        return render(request, 'freelance/create.html', context)
```

You also don't need this line in your view:

```
new_form.user = request.user
```

Comment: okay let me try it

Comment: i tried it now and this is the error i got  - Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Freelancers: destiny>]>": "Gigs.creator" must be a "Freelancers" instance.

Comment: okay, it means you need to use get instead of filter. just replace filter with get

Comment: okay let me try it

Comment: i think the error is gone, now i used get. but it now shows this - NOT NULL constraint failed: freelance_gigs.user_id

Comment: because the gig is already created now try creating another gig

Comment: okay, let me create another gig now

Comment: try logging in from another user

Comment: and you should also handle this user for better user experience. means if a gig already created from a specific user or id then you should display an error message to use if user try to create another gig with the same id

Comment: i just logged in from another user and created a new gig and it working fine. tnx alot.

Comment: can you please change the Freelancers.objects.filter(user = request.user ) above to Freelancers.objects.get(user = request.user ). So i can mark it as an answer?

Comment: edited with the correct code

Comment: i tried creating another gig but with the exact exising name of another gig. Then it throws a slug error like this - UNIQUE constraint failed: freelance_gigs.slug -  i dont know if you have an idea on what i should do

Comment: because at the moment only one user can create only one gig. you need to change your model structure

Comment: Your Gigs model have a relation of 1 to many, which means a user can create only 1 gig at the same time. If you want to allow a user to create multiple gigs using 1 account then you need to make a relation of many to many

Comment: okay let me change my model